# Troubles with .gitlab-ci.yml triggers configuration

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner, gitlab-omnibus

How should I set up my `.gitlab-ci.yml` manifest to run builds **ONLY** on:

- Merge Request;
- Push to branch with opened merge request from it (I mean when the merge request from branch Y to branch X is already opened and some new changes are pushed to branch Y);
- Push to master;

I've **tried to solve** it with a setting like this:

```
  job:
    only:
    - triggers
    - /merge-requests/
    - master
    except:
    - branches
```

Regarding on the documentation here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified

**Suddenly the error occurred** on my MR page:

> Could not connect to the CI server. Please check your settings and try again.

When I removed `only/except` restrictions from my manifest, the error was gone.

What am I doing wrong here?

My Gitlab **version** is: `GitLab Community Edition 10.8.1`

Answer (score 1):

You want to run a job only on:

1. merge request: I don't understand what you want here
2. Push to branch with opened merge request from it: you have to set a special job that call the Gitlab API to control that the current branch has a MR

```
A job executed only on new pushed branch:
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
  - # <-- add here the script that call Gitlab API
  only:
  - branches
```

3. Push to master:

```
A job executed only on master:
  image: alpine:latest
  script:
  - echo "Hello world!"
  only:
  - master
```

Comment: 1. I mean I need a job that will be executed on specific branch only if a MR from the specific branch exists to master;

2. So, do you want to say, that I need to create some extra utility jobs and re-request Gitlab API with curl when the job is triggered to achieve this behaviour?

Comment: I have a similar use case: I want to check for each commit if a MR exists if not create it. To solve this I have a job executed on each feature branch doing the check/creation. Here is an [example](https://gist.github.com/plajjan/42592665afd5ae045ee36220e19919aa#file-open-mr-sh) of a script of this type

Comment: As far as I know there is no condition saying "run this job only if the current branch has a MR"